# Create a dynamical custom control in JavaFX

Tags: model-view-controller, javafx, custom-controls

My goal is to *represent this* :

[image: File View Grid]

This is a `GridPane` of 3 columns :

- The first colum contains a `Label` that is the name of the file I just open
- The second column contains a `TextField` to represent the refresh rate
- The third colum contains a `CheckBox` and 2 `Button`

If the user open a file, I should add a line in this custom control, if there's no file open, the `GridPane` is empty.
I start my code with this :

**Control class**

```
package view.component.fileView;

import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;

public class FileViewGrid extends Control{

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin(){
        return new FileViewGridSkin(this);
    }
}
```

**Skin class**

```
package view.component.fileView;

import javafx.scene.control.SkinBase;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class FileViewGridSkin extends SkinBase<FileViewGrid>{

    protected FileViewGridSkin(FileViewGrid control) {
        super(control);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

But *the fact that lines are added dynamically confuse me*. If this was static, I will add all my element in my skin class, and their behavior in the control class, but right now this doesn't seems possible to me.

*Is this the right way to do it ? Should I use FXML method to create a custome control ?*

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a GridPane of 3 columns :

The first colum contains a Label that is the name of the file I just open
The second column contains a TextField to represent the refresh rate
The third colum contains a CheckBox and 2 Button
```

is this representing a cell of a ListView ?

if yes, you have a good start.
The secret is to play with [Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html) and [Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html)

In your Control you have to put what you want to expose to outside. For example, a Textfield have a textProperty().

In your case, you probably want to expose a List of your object which will be inside your ListView.

Your control will be something like :

```
package view.component.fileView;

import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;

public class FileViewGrid extends Control{

ListProperty<YourBean> list = new SimpleListProperty(FXCollection.emptyObservableList())

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin(){
        return new FileViewGridSkin(this);
    }
}
```

and your skin :

```
package view.component.fileView;

import javafx.scene.control.SkinBase;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class FileViewGridSkin extends SkinBase<FileViewGrid>{

FileViewGrid control;
Node root;
    protected FileViewGridSkin(FileViewGrid control) {
        super(control);
        this.control = control;
    }

        @Override
    public Node getNode() {
        if (root == null) {
            root = createRootNode();
        }
        return root;
    }

    public Node createRootNode(){
    //create your root node with something like: root = new Hbox() or whatever you want. Also you can load a FXML here.
      root = new Hbox();
     ListView<MyBean> listView = new ListView();
     listView.itemProperty().bind(control.list); //Here bind the listview items to your control list
    root.getChildrens().add(listView);
    }
}
```

and finnaly when you use your Control somewhere on your app :

```
FileViewGrid fileViewGrid = new FileViewGrid();
fileViewGrid.list.add(elem); //Here the listview in your control should be refreshed automaticaly cause of bindings.
```

And this is the same way for all type of component.

Also, you can checkout the [source](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/) of the [ControlFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) project which contains a lot of examples.

Comment: How could you put 3 cell on a row ?

Comment: You have to set a custom CellFactory to your listview http://java-buddy.blogspot.fr/2013/05/implement-javafx-listview-for-custom.html you can put what you want on a cell.

Comment: I finally diid it wih the help of your answer but there's some problems in your code, I will propose an update of your post soon.

Comment: cannot override the final method from SkinBase is what I get in 2017-07 for the getNode part

Comment: Yeah, `getNode` is `final` in `SkinBase` and I must be missing why they designed it that way. What is one supposed to do instead?